# Binary to decimal using horner

Tags: recursion, binary, decimal

1 x 2<sup>0</sup> +1 x 2<sup>1</sup> + 1 x 2<sup>2</sup> + 0 x 2<sup>3</sup> +1 x 2<sup>4</sup> = 1 + 2 x (1 + 2 x (1 + 2 x (0 + 2 x 1) ) )

Recall `b[0] = 1, b[1] = 1, b[2] = 1,b[3] = 0, b[4] = 1`

```
/* to convert a binary representation to a decimal one*/

int dec, b[5] = {1, 1, 1, 0, 1};
dec = b[4];
for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
{
    dec=2 * dec + b[i];  //horner's scheme
}
cout << dec << endl;
```

I tried to write this code again in C language, but it's not working correctly:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int B[5];
    int x, s, s1;

    for(int i = 1;i <= 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter %d. digit of binary number", i);
        scanf("%d", &B[i]);
    }


    s = B[5];   /*this part for reverse the array*/
    B[5] = B[1];
    B[1] = s;

    s1 = B[4];
    B[4] = B[2];
    B[2] = s1; 

    x = B[4];

    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        x = 2 * x + B[i];  
    }

    printf("%d", x);
    scanf("%d");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your initial loop where you initialise the array B

```
    int B[5];
    int x,s,s1;
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++) {
    printf("Enter %d. digit of binary number",i);
    scanf("%d",&B[i]);}
```

which is bad as you are accessing element `B[5]` which is outside the bounds of your array anyway, but also you are never initialising `B[0]` which you use in your second loop

```
    x=B[4];
    for (int i=3;i>=0;i--)
    {
        x=2*x+B[i];  
    }
```

try changing your first loop to

```
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        printf("Enter %d. digit of binary number",i);
        scanf("%d",&B[i]);
    }
```

and see if this gives the result you expect.

Also this code

```
    s=B[5];   /*this part for reverse the array*/
    B[5]=B[1];
    B[1]=s;

    s1=B[4];
    B[4]=B[2];
    B[2]=s1;
```

has problems, because you declared B as an array of 5 integers and since arrays have zero based indices, the only values for an index that are valid are from 0 to 4. If you want to  reverse the array correctly replace your code with

```
    s=B[4];   /*this part for reverse the array*/
    B[4]=B[0];
    B[0]=s;

    s1=B[3];
    B[3]=B[1];
    B[1]=s1;
```

**You must not access B[5] as this is outside the bounds of your array** !!!!

Comment: s=B[5];
B[5]=B[1];
B[1]=s;

s1=B[4];
B[4]=B[2];
B[2]=s1; 




I think there s problem here when i delete this part it s working but working for reverse of number. when i want to convert this 11000 it works for 00011 so i cant delete

Comment: Your code fails to set a value for B[0] therefore you cannot rely on it being what you think it is until you correct it.

Comment: @allstar Check the updated answer  - this should solve your problem now

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to revert the array.

Comment: but otherway when i want to convert this 11000 it works for 00011

Comment: @allstar Just to be sure: in which order do you enter the bits for the number 3:
11000 or 00011?

Comment: @allstar 3 = 1 x 2^0 +1 x 2^1 + 0 x 2^2 + 0 x 2^3 + 0 x 2^4
According to the beginning of your question:
3 -> b = {1,1,0,0,0}